# Fortify Bad Crypto error for Cipher getInstance method

Tags: java, android, fortify

I am trying to run fortify for my java code and I am stumbled with the following error. Can you someone please help?

`High Priority: An instance of Cipher.getInstance was found.
EncryptionUtils.java:137 (Unconditional: Bad Crypto) [83299E2C-B5DB-45F2-8CFE-01F3E6C0C02D]
55E277C045A4A6E410FCBF9BA5125E3E`

**Code Line in which I am getting this error**

`final Cipher aesCBCCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/Nopadding");`

Comment: Why do you specify `Nopadding`?

Comment: I tried with both `NoPadding` and `PKCS5Padding`. But both resulted in the same exception. I just used the same cipher transformation as mentioned by the link in the question.

Answer (score 0):

This might happen because of both the padding or the transformation. If you don't specify the transformation, the default of ECB is going to be assumed for both Java and Android, and that is not considered secure by Fortify.

I was having the same issue by specifying:

```
final Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
```

Fortify stopped complaining when I changed it to the following:

```
final Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
```

[Here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/crypto/Cipher.html), you can find the list of transformations that every JVM is required to support. And [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/javax/crypto/Cipher.html), for example, the ones supported by Android.

I suspect that the error you got is because using GCM requires extra steps (and if they're not provided, Cipher might be assuming another transformation by default -- I haven't verified that). Please see the following excerpt from the [Java docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/crypto/Cipher.html):

> AEAD modes such as GCM/CCM perform all AAD authenticity calculations before starting the ciphertext authenticity calculations. To avoid implementations having to internally buffer ciphertext, all AAD data must be supplied to GCM/CCM implementations (via the updateAAD methods) before the ciphertext is processed (via the update and doFinal methods).

If you open the Fortify Audit Workbench with the results of your analysis, that will give you further details and insight on your issue.